# How to stretch the screen size of a separate virtual desktop beyond the monitor?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, desktop

I have few virtual desktops. I need to stretch the entire screen of one of them to the size that will not fit on the monitor. I tried the following:

```
    HWND entire_screen = GetDesktopWindow();
    if (!SetWindowPos(entire_screen, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000,  SWP_NOSENDCHANGING))
    {
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
```

The function doesn't work, nothing changes, GetLastError() returns 0, as if everything went fine.

Tried to change the resolution of the virtual desktop:

```
    HWND entire_screen = GetDesktopWindow();
    DEVMODE devMode;
    if (!EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode))
    {
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    devMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    devMode.dmPelsWidth = 3000;
    devMode.dmPelsHeight = 3000;
    devMode.dmFields = DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH;

    LONG result = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(0, &devMode, entire_screen, 
                                                           CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES, 0);
    if (result != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
        return 0;
```

In this attempt, ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returns the result of code -5 (DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM). Tried different flags / without flags, specify a lower resolution - nothing helped, the function never worked.

Please tell me why my code doesn't work, or tell how else can I solve the task ?

Comment: The behavior of the window returned by `GetDesktopWindow` is an implementation detail. It is not meant for you to resize. Besides, there is a virtual desktop API built into Windows. You're just not using it at all. Start with the [VirtualDesktopManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186461.aspx).

Comment: This actually sounds like XY problem. Why do you need to stretch anything?